# Can anyone help me find books published in 2005 or before?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, group-by

Display the publisher id and name of the publishers who supply both books with a topic id of MySQL and books with a topic id of DB. The books must have a publication year of 2005 or later. These do not have to be the same book. Display only one row per publisher who meets the test.

My Solution:

```
  select DISTINCT publ_id, publ_name
from a_bkinfo.publishers 
join a_bkinfo.books using (publ_id)
join a_bkinfo.book_topics using (book_id)
join a_bkorders.order_details using (book_id)
join a_bkorders.order_headers USING (order_id)
where book_id in    (
        Select book_id   
        From a_bkinfo.book_topics     
        Where topic_id = 'SQL'
        )
 And book_id in  (    
        Select book_id   
        From a_bkinfo.book_topics     
        Where topic_id = 'DB'
        )
 And book_id in
       Select book_id    
        From a_bkinfo.book_topics
        Where year(order_date) > 2005 

        );
```

Here are the tables:

```
   -- create publishers
create table a_bkinfo.publishers (
   publ_id           integer          not null
 , publ_name         varchar(25)      not null  
 , constraint bk_publishers_pk        primary key(publ_id) 
 , constraint publ_id_range check (publ_id >1000)
)engine = INNODB;

  -- create books
create table a_bkinfo.books (
    book_id           integer          not null
  , title             varchar(75)      not null 
  , publ_id           integer          null
  , year_publd        integer          not null
  , isbn              varchar(17)      null
  , page_count        integer          null  
  , list_price        numeric(6,2)     null  
  , constraint bk_books_pk             primary key (book_id)
  , constraint bk_books_publ_fk        foreign key(publ_id) 
               references a_bkinfo.publishers  (publ_id)
  , constraint book_id_range           check (book_id > 1000)
  , constraint bk_page_count_ck        check (page_count >= 0)
  , constraint bk_price_ck             check (list_price >= 0)             
  , constraint bk_books_year_ck        check (year_publd >= 1850)
)engine = INNODB;

  -- create book_topics
create  table a_bkinfo.book_topics (
    book_id           integer          not null
  , topic_id          varchar(5)       not null  
  , constraint bk_book_topics_pk        primary key (book_id, topic_id)
  , constraint bk_books_topics_fk      foreign key(topic_id) 
               references a_bkinfo.topics(topic_id)
  , constraint bk_books_id_fk          foreign key(book_id) 
               references a_bkinfo.books(book_id)
)engine = INNODB;

  -- create order_headers 
create  table   a_bkorders.order_headers (
    order_id          integer          not null 
  , order_date        date             not null
  , cust_id           integer          not null 
  , constraint bk_orders_pk            primary key (order_id)
  , constraint bk_orders_cust_fk       foreign key(cust_id) 
               references a_bkorders.customers(cust_id) 
  , constraint bk_order_id_range       check (order_id > 100)
 ,  constraint bk_order_date_ck        check (order_date >=  '2000-01-01')
)engine = INNODB;

  -- create order_details  
create  table   a_bkorders.order_details (
    order_id          integer          not null 
  , order_line        integer          not null 
  , book_id           integer          not null 
  , quantity          integer          not null 
  , order_price       numeric(6,2)     not null   
  , constraint bk_orderline_pk         primary key (order_id, order_line)
  , constraint bk_orderline_order_fk   foreign key (order_id) 
               references a_bkorders.order_headers(order_id) on delete cascade
  , constraint bk_orderline_book_fk    foreign key (book_id )  
               references a_bkinfo.books(book_id)
  , constraint bk_quantity_ck          check (quantity > 0) 
  , constraint bk_ordprice_ck          check (order_price >= 0) 
)engine = INNODB;
```

Here are some inserts:

```
       -- publishers
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9000, 'Microsoft Press') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9456, 'New Directions') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9102, 'Alfred A. Knopf') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9325, 'Addison Wesley') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9745, 'Morgan Kaufmann') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9521, 'Benjamin/Cummings') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9822, 'O''Reilly') ; 
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9030, 'McGraw Hill') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9444, 'APress') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9528, 'Manning');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9020, 'Princeton Univer Press') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9021, 'Yale University Press') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9022, 'Havard University Press') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9507, 'J.Q. Vanderbildt');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9664, 'WROX') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9825, 'MySQL Press') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9623, 'Prentice Hall') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9725, 'Springer') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9561, 'Houghton Mifflin'); 
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9902, 'W.W. Norton ') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9023, 'Holt Paperbacks') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9024, 'Univ of California Press') ;
    Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9776, 'Simon and Schuster') ;


    -- topics
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('ADO',   'ADO');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('CMP',   'Computer Science');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('DB',    'Database Systems');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('FCT',   'Fiction');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('HIST',  'History');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('MySQL', 'MySQL Database');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('NET',   '.NET Technologies');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('NOSQL', 'Alternate Data Storage');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('ORA',   'Oracle Database');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('POE',   'Poetry');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('PGM',   'General Programming');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('SCI',   'Science');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('SQL',   'SQL');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('SSRV',  'SQL Server Database');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('VB',    'Visual Basic');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('XML',   'XML Techniques');
    Insert into a_bkinfo.topics values ('ART',   'Arts, Photography');


    -- books  
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1101, 'Programming SQL Server with VB.NET',              9000, 2002, '0735615357',    300, 59.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1102, 'Practical Standards for VB.NET',                  9000, 2003, '0735613568',    250, 49.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1103, 'Selected Poems',                                  9456, 1949,  null,           125, 12.00);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1104, 'Sibley Guide to Bird Life and Behavior',          9102, 2001, '0679451234',    604, 45.00);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1105, 'SQL:1999 Relational Language Concepts',           9745, 2002, '1558604561',    450, 59.95);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1106, 'SQL for Smarties',                                9745, 1995, '1558603239',    250, 29.00);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1107, 'SQL Puzzles and Answers',                         9745, 1997, '1558604537',    325, 25.00);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1108, 'Database Systems',                                9325, 1996,  null,           680, 39.95);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1109, 'Intro to DB Systems-7th Ed',                      9325, 2000, '0201385902',    650, 80.00);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1110, 'Adv SQL:1999 Object_Relational Features',         9745, 2002, '1558606077',    520, 59.95);


    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1128, 'Temporal Data and the Relational Model',          9325, 2003, 'na',            275, 49.95);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1133, 'Leaves of Grass',                                 9623, 1902,  null,           125, 19.95);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1142, 'Relational Database Theory',                      9521, 1993,  null,           879, 95.00);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1161, 'SQL Programming Style',                           9745, 2005, '0120887975',    780, 35.00);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1162, 'Trees and Hierarchies',                           9745, 2004, '1558609202',    350, 35.00);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1180, 'MySQL Database Design and Tuning',                9825, 2005, '9780672234650', 400, 49.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1175, 'MySQL in a Nutshell',                             9822, 2008, '9780596514331', 538, 34.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1182, 'MySQL Cookbook',                                  9822, 2007, '9780596527082', 918, 49.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1185, 'MySQL Stored Procedures',                         9822, 2007, '9780596100896', 595, 49.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1184, 'MySQL Developer''s Library',                      9325, 2009, '9780672329388', 650, 49.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1301, 'ADO and Oracle Workbook',                         9000, 2002, '0265615357',      0, 59.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1302, 'ADO: the ebook',                                  9000, 2002, '0852515358',   null, 49.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1303, 'Rainbows and Rainbows',                           9521, 2002, '0657895157',   null, 59.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1304, 'Stories of Discoveries',                          9325, 2002, '0777788887',    300, 59.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1305, 'Journeys Through Flatland',                       9325, 1958, '0387515357',    100,  9.99);
    insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1306, 'Myths of SQL',    

                                9664, 2000, '0454615027',   2895,259.99);
Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30822,  '2012-03-12', 211483);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30822, 1, 1128,  10,  49.95);   

/* Apr 2012 */

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30824, '2012-04-05', 222477);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30824, 1, 1670, 10,  40.00);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30824, 4, 2005, 20,  45.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(2001,  '2012-04-02', 272787);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2001, 1, 1448, 50,  25.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(2002,  '2012-04-12', 272787);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2002, 1, 1103,  20,  10.95);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(2003,  '2012-04-12', 272787);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2003, 1, 1103,  2,  12.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1564,  '2012-04-18', 227105);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1564, 1, 1106,  50,  34.95);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1564, 2, 1107,  50,  20.95);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1564, 3, 2001,  50,  39.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1800,  '2012-04-12', 217796);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1800, 1, 2009,  5,  34.95);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1800, 2, 2008,  1,  46.95);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1801, '2012-04-13', 217796);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1801, 1, 1103,  2,  10.95);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1801, 2, 1106,  1,  29.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30825, '2012-04-21', 221297);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30825, 1, 1776,  4,  45.49);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30826,  '2012-04-24', 211483);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30826, 2, 1161,  16,  35.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30833,  '2012-04-14', 211483);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30833, 1, 1448, 50,  25.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30834,  '2012-04-17', 211483);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30834, 1, 1128,  1,  49.95);

/* May 2012 */

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30835,  '2012-05-17', 211483);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30835, 1, 1103,  25,  10.95);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30836,  '2012-05-20', 258595);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30836, 1, 2008,  2,  12.50);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1811,  '2012-05-12', 221297);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1811, 1, 2007,  1,  40.49);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1811, 2, 1357,  2,  23.40);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1811, 3, 1537,  3,  28.19);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1812,  '2012-05-12', 227105);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1812, 1, 2009,  1,  26.99);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1814,  '2012-05-15', 290298);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1814, 1, 1258,  1,  45.99);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1818,  '2012-05-16', 212921);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1818, 1, 1106, 30,  20.00);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1818, 2, 1537,  2,  25.00);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1818, 3, 1180,  1,  46.99);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1818, 4, 1979,  1,  53.99);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1710,  '2012-05-08', 261502);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1710, 1, 1776,  99,  45.49);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1712,  '2012-05-09', 290298);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1712, 1, 1835,  1,  45.99);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1712, 2, 1162,  99,  30.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(2004,  '2012-05-22', 272787);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2004, 2, 1161,  1,  35.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(2005,  '2012-05-30', 272787);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2005, 1, 1448, 50,  25.00); 

/* June 2012 */

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(2012,  '2012-06-22', 272787);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2012, 1, 1448, 50,  25.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(2013,  '2012-06-22', 272787);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(2013, 1, 2009,  2,  12.50);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30847,  '2012-06-20', 296598);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30847, 1, 1103,  2,  12.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30848,  '2012-06-21', 263119);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30848, 1, 2007,  2,  12.50);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(30849,  '2012-06-22', 217796);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(30849, 1, 1448, 50,  25.00);

/* July 2012 */   

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(31840,  '2012-07-01', 267780);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(31840, 1, 1103,  2,  12.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(31841,  '2012-07-02', 272787);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(31841, 1, 1448, 50,  25.00);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(31850,  '2012-07-02', 234138);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(31850, 1, 1279,  1,  40.49);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1045,  '2012-07-18', 222477);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1045, 1, 1894,  1,  35.99);   

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1200,  '2012-07-18', 212921);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1200, 1, 1200,  5,  16.33);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1200, 2, 1199,  5,  18.39);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1200, 3, 1457,  5,  53.99);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1200, 4, 1133,  5,  18.15);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1200, 5, 1894,  5,  36.79);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1200, 6, 1948,  5,  40.94);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1200, 7, 1180,  5,  45.99);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1200, 8, 1128,  5,  46.20);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1205,  '2012-07-20', 212921);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1205, 1, 1448,  1,  27.29);

Insert into a_bkorders.order_headers    values(1212,  '2012-07-20', 290298);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1212, 1, 1894,  1,  37.59);
   Insert into a_bkorders.order_details values(1212, 2, 1894,  1,  18.75);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.publ_id, p.publ_name, oh.order_date
FROM a_bkinfo.publishers p 
JOIN a_bkinfo.books b USING (publ_id)
JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics bt USING (book_id)
JOIN a_bkorders.order_details od USING (book_id)
JOIN a_bkorders.order_headers oh USING (order_id)
WHERE bt.topic_id IN ('SQL', 'DB') AND YEAR(oh.order_date) >= 2005 
GROUP BY p.publ_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT bt.topic_id) = 2;
```

Comment: Wow, I made problem to complicated.

Comment: This looks like "either", but the OP asked for "both"

Comment: You are right. Just noticed that. Could you elaborate with an example please?

Comment: I edited the answer above to fit "both" not "either".

Comment: Yeah, that should work. Sorry I couldn't be more constructive. MySQL is unfamiliar to me. I was thinking of joining to two instances of book_topics and filter one by "SQL" and the other by "DB". The use of the HAVING clause is a better approach, though.

Answer (score 0):

First, a warning. I think this is the first MySQL query I have ever written! So I may not have the syntax right. The way you are joining is strange to me. In my experience, the join is a little more explicit as to what is joined to what and on what fields. I'm also unsure of including publ_name and order_date in the SELECT clause but not in the GROUP BY. Would this produce multiple results per publisher regardless of the GROUP BY clause?

Saharsh's approach is better, but an alternative might look something like this:

```
SELECT 
  p.publ_id, 
  max(p.publ_name) as publ_name, 
  max(oh.order_date) as order_date
FROM 
  a_bkinfo.publishers p INNER JOIN a_bkinfo.books b 
    ON p.publ_id = b.publ_id
  INNER JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics bt 
    ON b.book_id = bt.book_id
  INNER JOIN a_bkinfo.book_topics bt2
    ON b.book_id = bt2.book_id
  INNER JOIN a_bkorders.order_details od 
    ON b.book_id = od.book_id
  INNER JOIN a_bkorders.order_headers oh 
    ON od.order_id = oh.order_id
WHERE 
  bt.topic_id = 'SQL' AND 
  bt2.topic_id = 'DB' AND 
  YEAR(oh.order_date) >= 2005 
GROUP BY 
  p.publ_id
```